# Array of genvar in SystemVerilog

Tags: digital-logic, system-verilog

I'm trying to implement a Dadda tree multiplier in SystemVerilog using `generate` blocks. However, the algorithm I'm using to instantiate the logic requires arrays, and the `genvar` type does not seem to support arrays. In theory, I could use some external script to produce the required Verilog code, but that would be difficult to write and verify.

As part of the Dadda tree algorithm, I have to keep track of the heights of each partial sum column. For example, here is the first part of the algorithm:

```
logic [62:0][31:0] products[STAGES];

genvar i, j;
// Heights of each partial sum column
genvar colHeights[STAGES][63:0]; // syntax error

generate
    // Record all the initial products
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) begin : a_loop
        for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) begin : b_loop
            assign products[0][i+j][colHeights[0][i+j]] = a[i] & b[j];
            colHeights[0][i+j] = colHeights[0][i+j] + 1;
        end
    end

    // ...
endgenerate
```

`colHeights` is supposed to be a multidimensional array, but my compiler does not seem to recognize that.

Is there a way to create arrays which can be read from and written to during module instantiation? If not, is there another way I can instantiate modules based on the results of an algorithm like this?

Comment: A `genvar` is just a loop iterator that gets unrolled into a constant at compilation. It is not a variable. You need to explain what kind of _array_ you want; an array of wires, variables, or module instantiations. It might help to show a piece of code without using `generate` that manually describes what you want to do.

Comment: At some point, it may become useful to use a more general-purpose language (e.g., [Python](https://myhdl.org)) to generate the structures you want.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. Describe your problem first, not the attempted solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a nested for-loop in Verilog?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/524683/how-to-create-a-nested-for-loop-in-verilog)

Comment: I added some details about the kind of algorithm I'm looking for.

Comment: In the provided examples a `generate` block should not be used because `colHeights` increments and `product` will have many indexes with multiple drivers. Use an `always_comb` block instead

Comment: @Greg Each index of `products` will have at most one driver because the corresponding `colHeights` entry increments each time one is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `colHeights` to be declared as a `genvar`. You can declare it the same way as you are declaring `products` (that is, as a `logic` array), and write and read it inside the generate loops. As long as you avoid writing to the same slice in multiple iterations, there will be no multiple driver issues.

A `genvar` has a single purpose only, which is to use as a generate loop iterator. I prefer to put the declaration inside the for-statement, like this:

```
for (genvar i = 0; i < 32; i++) begin : a_loop
```

Comment: `colHeights` is never accessed after instantiation, but it needs to be read and written multiple times during instantiation. I'm looking for an array type that can be used *before* module instantiation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. What I can tell you is that `genvar` is not what you are looking for, because the only legal use for `genvar` is generate loop iterators. If you are looking to conditionally instantiate modules inside your loop, perhaps you could write a function, and call that function in a generate-if?